# Group By with date column in the having clause

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

```
customer    price   date
123         100     1-Jan-15
321         200     2-Jan-15
123         10      3-Jan-15
123         50      4-Jan-15
321         150     5-Jan-15
123         100     6-Jan-15
123         300     7-Jan-15
321         500     8-Jan-15
123         700     9-Jan-15
```

I would like to take see SUM(Price) between dates 3-Jan and 7-Jan group by customer

Something like:

```
select customer,sum(price) from table group by customer 
having date between 3-Jan-2015 and 8-Jan-2015
```

This prompts me to have `date` either in the `select` or `group by` clause. When I include it, it groups by Date also.

Desired output is:

```
123 460
```

Comment: customer price date
123 100 1-Jan-15
123 200 2-Jan-15
123 10 3-Jan-15
123 50 4-Jan-15
321 150 5-Jan-15
123 100 6-Jan-15
123 300 7-Jan-15
321 500 8-Jan-15
123 700 9-Jan-15

Comment: I think you want the `date between...` in the `where` clause, not the `having` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause filters results *after* the grouping and aggregation, so in order to do this any fields you want in the `HAVING` clause must be in the `GROUP BY` or `SELECT` lists.  The `WHERE` clause filters the rows *before* doing the grouping and aggregation.

To get the results you want, simply move the `date between...` condition into a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT customer,SUM(price)
  FROM table
  WHERE date BETWEEN 3-Jan-2015 AND 8-Jan-2015
  GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: No, the `having` can be use without `group by`, and it will act like `where`